# Quasar q-select display nothing when I choose one of the options

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

New to Quasar, and I try to create a `q-select` that getting as options a list of objects. So far, I achieved to display the options in the dropdown, but when I select an element, the `q-select` remains empty although the page component data value is filled properly.

See the following git for more info:

[image]

My `q-select` implementation is like this:

```
<template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <q-select
        v-model="parentCategory"
        clearable
        use-input
        input-debounce="350"
        label="Parent Category"
        :options="businessCategoriesToSelect"
        :option-label="opt => Object(opt) === opt && 'title' in opt ? opt.title : null"
        :option-value="opt => Object(opt) === opt && '@id' in opt ? opt['@id'] : null"
        :display-value="Object(parentCategory) === parentCategory && 'title' in parentCategory ? parentCategory.title : null"
        emit-value
    >
        <template v-slot:no-option>
            <q-item>
                <q-item-section class="text-grey">
                    No Business Categories Found
                </q-item-section>
            </q-item>
        </template>
    </q-select>
    <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
// ...

export default {
    // ...
    data() {
        return {
            // ...
            parentCategory            : null,
            // ...
            businessCategoriesToSelect: [],
            // ...
        };
    },
    // ...
}
</script>
```

The objects loaded in the `businessCategoriesToSelect` have the following form:

[image]

And when I select one of the options in the `q-select` item the data property that is responsible to hold the selected value it has a value like this:

[image]

But although all seems to be OK with what I did, the `q-select` still don't like to display the proper value.

Any idea on how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answer to my self just to provide my solution in order to help any other person has the same problem with me.

Finally I solved the problem by using the slot `selected-item`. The final solution is like that:

```
<q-select
    v-model="parentCategory"
    clearable
    use-input
    input-debounce="350"
    label="Parent Category"
    :options="businessCategoriesToSelect"
    :option-label="opt => Object(opt) === opt && 'title' in opt ? opt.title : null"
    :option-value="opt => Object(opt) === opt && '@id' in opt ? opt['@id'] : null"
    :display-value="Object(parentCategory) === parentCategory && 'title' in parentCategory ? parentCategory.title : null"
    emit-value
    map-options
>
   <template v-slot:no-option>
       <q-item>
            <q-item-section class="text-grey">
                No Business Categories Found
            </q-item-section>
        </q-item>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:selected-item="scope">
        {{ scope.opt.title }}
    </template>
</q-select>
```

Comment: I wonder since 3 week, how do you get the emitted value in the parent component please.

Comment: @XimazeC you may give a look in the documentation [here](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#the-model) and the `emit-value`. It's long time since I wrote this code, and I cannot recall now what I did. But the documentation is more that good, and ofcourse I received the answer from there :)

Comment: I read this documentation since weeks and still don't have any idea of the name of the event that is triggerred, the makes me loose my mind